# Query migration for mssql to mysql

Tags: mysql

I have stuck with a query of mssql. The query runs successfully in mssql but it is taking endless time in mysql.

```
SELECT employee.ecode, fname, mname, lname
FROM employee
WHERE employee.cmp_dol IS NULL
AND employee.ecode IN (
    SELECT leave_log.ecode
    FROM leave_log
    WHERE (
        l_acc_code = 11
        OR l_acc_code = 21
        OR l_acc_code = 31
        OR l_acc_code = 41
        OR l_acc_code = 51
        OR l_acc_code = 61
    )
    AND leave_log.l_date NOT IN (
        SELECT leave_log.l_date
        FROM leave_log
        WHERE l_acc_code = 91
        GROUP BY leave_log.ecode, l_date, l_acc_code
        HAVING SUM(l_value)<>0
    )
    GROUP BY leave_log.ecode, l_date, l_acc_code
    HAVING SUM(l_value) <> 0)
UNION
SELECT employee.ecode, fname, mname, lname
FROM employee
WHERE employee.cmp_dol IS NULL
AND employee.ecode IN (
    SELECT leave_log.ecode
    FROM leave_log
    WHERE l_acc_code = 91
    GROUP BY leave_log.ecode, l_date, l_acc_code
    HAVING SUM(l_value)<>0
)
ORDER BY fname
```

Comment: Check your indexes. It's likely that the tables in mysql don't have the proper indexes set.

Comment: Run: `show create table <tablename>` the indexes will be listed at the bottom of the resulting statement.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `leave_log` (
  `ecode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `l_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_acc_code` decimal(18,0) NOT NULL,
  `l_value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `tran_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` char(99) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apply_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: You could also run your statement with `EXPLAIN` just before it.  That will give you the execution plan.

Comment: That means you have no indexes.  You need to add some.  You probably need one on ecode.  I'm not sure if that would be your primary key.

Comment: if I replace the IN and NOT IN clause with EXISTS and NOT EXISTS clause, the query runs but output is wrong.

Comment: Prior to MySQL 5.6, `in` with a subquery was simply very, very inefficient.  You need to rewrite this part of the code to use joins or exists.